# Woocommerce - Adicionar campos para exportar através de REST_API Webhook

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce

Como faço para adicionar campos na parte de exportar pedidos no Webhook REST_API? No caso adicionei os campos data de nascimento, cpf e cnpj no Woocommerce mas não estou conseguindo adicionar os mesmos para exportação via Webhook REST_API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Abordagem 1

Os webhooks do woocommerce fornecem os dados do recurso que você escolheu receber e somente dados do recurso, como data de nascimento, CPF, CNPJ, são dados de clientes esses dados não serão inclusos no webhook de pedidos.

Quando você receber uma chamada do webhook de `order` você terá todos os dados do pedido incluindo o `customer_id`.

Com o `customer_id` em mãos você pode fazer uma chamada para a API de `/customers/{{ customer_id }}` e recuperar os metadados desse cliente.

Exemplo de resposta da API de `customer` (v3):

```
{
    "id": 123,
    ...
    "meta_data": []
}
```

> https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-a-customer

Os dados que você precisa estarão na chave `meta_data`, o conteúdo dessa chave depende de como os dados foram salvos na base.

#### Abordagem 2

Agora se você quiser alterar os dados do payload enviados pelo webhook sem cosiderar contexto, você pode utilizar o filtro de `woocommerce_webhook_payload`, exemplo:

```
function modify_order_webhook_payload( $payload, $resource, $resource_id, $id ) {
    if ( $resource !== 'order' ) {
        return $payload;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $payload['id'] );
    $user = $order->get_user();

    // Lê os metadados de usuário

    $payload['data_nascimento'] = null; // adiciona a info
    $payload['cpf'] = null; // adiciona a info
    $payload['cnpj'] = null; // adiciona a info


    return $payload;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_webhook_payload', 'modify_order_webhook_payload', 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score -4):

Para adicionar campos personalizados em uma exportação de pedidos via Webhook REST_API do WooCommerce, é necessário modificar o código do webhook e incluir os novos campos. Você pode seguir os seguintes passos:

1- Acesse a seção "Webhooks" no painel do WooCommerce e localize o webhook que você deseja modificar.

2- Copie a URL do webhook e a chave de autenticação. Você precisará delas para realizar os testes e fazer as alterações.

3-Crie um script em uma linguagem de programação compatível com o WooCommerce REST API. Por exemplo, você pode usar o PHP para criar um script que se conecte à API e exporte os pedidos.

4- No script, adicione os campos personalizados que você criou no WooCommerce. Por exemplo, se você criou os campos "data_de_nascimento", "cpf" e "cnpj", você pode adicionar esses campos na requisição da API como parâmetros adicionais, conforme abaixo:

```
   $params = array(
   'status' => 'completed',
   'date_created' => '2022-02-01',
   'meta_data' => array(
      array(
         'key' => 'data_de_nascimento',
         'value' => '1990-01-01'
      ),
      array(
         'key' => 'cpf',
         'value' => '123.456.789-00'
      ),
      array(
         'key' => 'cnpj',
         'value' => '12.345.678/0001-00'
      )
   )
);
```

5- Teste a sua implementação utilizando as informações de URL e chave de autenticação que você copiou do webhook no passo 2. Você pode utilizar um software como o Postman ou realizar testes diretamente na sua aplicação.

6- Se os testes forem bem-sucedidos, faça as alterações necessárias no código do webhook para incluir os novos campos personalizados.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta. No passo 6, como faço para incluir no webhook os novos campos personalizados? Pois já criei os campos aonde o cliente se cadastra no WooCommerce, porém não sei aonde inserir para que estes sejam exportados através do Webhook REST_API.

Comment: Respostas geradas pelo ChatGPT são proibidas.